# После нажатия на кнопку TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Бот запускается без ошибок, и когда нажму на кнопку который создал выдаёт ошибку

```
    bot.send_message(chat_info[0], message.text)
                     ~~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Проблема в этот пункт
`bot.send_message(chat_info[0], message.text)`

Comment: `chat_info` не является индексируемым, это переменная типа `Bool`, хранящая в себе либо `True`, либо `False`. Короче говоря, логический тип не является последовательностью, следовательно индексировать его не получится. Полагаю, для решения проблемы, нужно больше контекста, приложите еще кода о формировании `chat_info` в вопрос.

Comment: А что такое chat_info? И что должно получиться из chat_info[0]?